# How do you update storage class of AWS s3 object with Rails/ActiveStorage?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, rails-activestorage

It looks like I can do this with the AWS S3 CLI, but is it possible with Rails?

```
object = bucket.objects(prefix: "04kywr03bqrs7so97yaksnd3x7w").first
object.storage_class
=> "GLACIER_IR"
object.storage_class = "ONEZONE_IA"
NoMethodError (undefined method `storage_class=' for #<Aws::S3::ObjectSummary:0x00005624afbf7c08>)
```